# run Linux commands in Lua program

Tags: lua, openwrt

im want to use lua to reset one of the openwrt`s Linux services . when i use below command in Linux directly and it works :

```
$ service
```

it shows below services
[image]
when i type below command it shows me more options :

```
$ service led
```

[image]
finally when i type below command it resets the service .

```
$ service led restart
```

but with lua`s below program i got error .

```
>os.execute("service led restart")
sh: service: not found
```

is there any other library or command to access services ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command -V service` says:

> service is a function

To be able to invoke it in a subshell created by `os.execute` you have to `source` the script which creates the function. (I don't know where this function was defined).

The more easy way is to invoke the specific service executable:

```
os.execute"/etc/init.d/led restart"
```